# How to start an Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I just following a tutorial to start a basic `intent`, and I get an error. Doing exact the same as the tutorial, created an empty `Activity` and just passed as argument to the `intent`. What is the problem?

[image]

Using a video tutorial: Lynda.com - Developing Android Apps Essential Training (2015)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial you were following?

Comment: use `YourActivity.this ` in place of `this `.

Comment: Your anonymous subclass of `com.facebook.GraphRequest.Callback` is not a `Context`.

Comment: It is a video tutorial: Lynda.com - Developing Android Apps Essential Training (2015)

Comment: -3 is because you didn't search on the web before asking it.

Answer (score 1):

The error you've got in IDE usually happens when you try to use Activity Context (keyword `this`) inside some callback, listener or anonymous function. In such situation `this` does not refer to the Context of the Activity.

That's why solution provided by @Vishal Patoliya should fix your problem because you're explicitly referring to the Context of the concrete Activity as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this,ItemUserSettingRattingActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this,ItemUserSettingRattingActivity.class);

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Could you explain why **YourActivity.this** is better then simple the **this**?

Comment: your current class name

Comment: you written this try catch so every time it takes this as from try catch and not getting current class in nested methods so we must use ouractivityname.this rather then simple this

Comment: @János you use intent is in `com.facebook.GraphRequest.Callback` so here `this` is represent your Callback context not your activity context. If you use Intent inside any Listener or Callback `this` not represent your Activity context, it represent Listener or callback context.

Answer (score 0):

**In case of Activtiy, you are going to another activity:--**

```
Intent intent = new 
Intent(YourActivity.this,ItemUserSettingRattingActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**If you are passing intent from a fragment to open a activity then**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ItemUserSettingRattingActivity.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already created a class named ItemUserSettingRattingActivity.java? maybe you get an error it's because the intent you created didn't detect the class.